# How would I use terminal to disable my camera for macOS Catalina (Version 10.15.3)?

Tags: terminal, camera, macos-catalina

I have tried a lot of the older methods to disable the camera on my MacBook, however, none of them seem to be working. I keep receiving the message "Operation not permitted." I would also need to know how to re-enable the camera afterward. The link attached is one of the methods I have tried. Any help would be very much appreciated.

https://www.macobserver.com/tips/macos-disable-webcam-mac/